# Using IPrincipal in with MVC3 AuthorizationAttribute and avoiding RoleProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a WCF service that returns an an object that implements both IPrinciple and IIdentity.

I assumed that somehow I could hook this up to the MVC3 authorization system without having to create a RoleProvider

e.g. so I could do something like this in my AccountController logon method:

```
// AthenticatedUser implments both IPrinciple and IIdentity

AthenticatedUser user = wcfService.Logon(password, userName);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);

// Set IPrinciple so I can use IsInRole method elsewhere (or AuthorizationAttribute can reuse it)
this.HttpContext.User = authenticationClient.AuthenticatedUser;
```

Then by some magic when I use

`[Authorize (Roles = "foo", "bar")]`

the IsInRole method of my AuthenticatedUser gets called.

However in my testing / debugging I have found that this.HttpContext.User does not seem to maintained across requests.

Edit sorry: I should have made it clear that I don't want to have to call my WCF service on each request, I'd like to somehow cache / store the user and roles and be able to use the AuthorizeAttribute with the IPrinciple comeing from my service.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IIS 7 to run this on your local machine add this to web.config under system.webServer:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
      <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
      <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
      <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 2):

You say "this.HttpContext.User does not seem to maintained across requests" - that is the correct behavior. Each request has a unique `HttpContext`.

What you might want to try is this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

, which creates a durable cookie that lasts between browser sessions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, the `HttpContext` is not persisted across requests and hence neither are `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` - the `HttpContext` is constructed at the start of each request by the framework, and the `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` are constructed from the authentication ticket deserialised from the authentication cookie.

What you are describing sounds similar in some ways to a **[WCF authentication service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx)**. In this scenario, the service will authenticate the user and send back an authentication cookie in the response to the calling application, and that application will then use the cookie to construct the `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` on each subsequent request.

You can override the `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` when the `Application.PostAuthenticateRequest` event is raised

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.User != null)
    {
        var identity = Context.User.Identity;

        // define our own IIdentity and IPrincipal for an authenticated user
        if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            // get the roles from somewhere
            var roles = GetRoles(); 

            identity = new CustomIdentity(ticket.Name);
            IPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(identity, roles);
            Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that the roles need to be retrieved from somewhere. With a RoleProvider in place, these roles can be cached in another cookie. *If you know what you're doing* in terms of security, you could look at replicating how the roles are serialized and encrypted in the cookie.

An alternative may be to store the roles in session and may be adequate for a small number of roles. Bear in mind that session is not available until the `PostAcquireRequestState` event has been raised, some **[7 events later in the application request lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)** than `PostAuthenticateRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to react in your global asax on the AuthenticateRequest event and change the IIdentity like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        this.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_AuthenticateRequest);
    }

    void MvcApplication_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var key = "User-" + name;
            var principal = HttpContext.Current.Cache["User-" + name];
            if (principal == null)
            {
                principal = GetYourUserAsIPrincipal();
                // Add to cache for 1 hour with sliding expiration
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, principal, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            }
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal ;
        }
    }        
}
```

**EDIT**: For caching you can use the default ASP.NET Caching. I've edited the above sample. Note, the ASP.NET cache is thread safe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

It would be the best, if you wrap all of your cache access logic into a single class.

As with any caching mechanism: If you change your users roles, it will be reflected only when the cache has been expired.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I should have made it clear that I don't want to have to call my WCF service on each request, I'd like to somehow cache / store the user and roles and be able to use the AuthorizeAttribute with the IPrinciple comeing from my service. - added this note to my orginal question.